# How to create custom email header

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

I see in transactional email New order template, there is this tag that calls the header html file which is in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/html`

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
```

I wish to create a new header so I created new file `app/local/en_US/template/email/html/header2.html` and use code

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header2"}}
```

but it does not work. With this code, no header is included in the email. Any ideas why or what is the proper way to create a custom email header?

Comment: do you have a header defined under the config path `design/email/header2`

Comment: Yes, I do. I believe the correct path is. app/local/en_US/template/email/html/header2.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can also implement the class default Magento to work with multiple (headers and footers).

Create file:

> app/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Email/Template.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Adminhtml config system template source
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Email_Template extends Varien_Object
{
    /**
     * Config xpath to email template node
     *
     */
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_EMAIL = 'global/template/email/';

    /**
     * Generate list of email templates
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if(!$collection = Mage::registry('config_system_email_template')) {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('core/email_template_collection')
            ->load();

            Mage::register('config_system_email_template', $collection);
        }
        $options = $collection->toOptionArray();
        $templateName = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Default Template from Locale');
        $nodeName = str_replace('/', '_', $this->getPath());

        // Implementation for various templates config.
        $templatesNodes = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('global/template/email');
        if(count($templatesNodes)) {
            foreach($templatesNodes as $nodes) {
                foreach($nodes as $code => $config) {
                    if(strpos($code, $nodeName) !== false) {
                        $templateLabelNode = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_EMAIL . $code . '/label');
                        if ($templateLabelNode) {
                            $templateName = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__((string)$templateLabelNode);
                            $templateName = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('%s (Default Template from Locale)', $templateName);
                        }
                        array_unshift(
                            $options,
                            array(
                                'value'=> str_replace('/', '_', $code),
                                'label' => $templateName
                                )
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }

}
```

Then in your custom module, you can use as in the following example in your config.xml:

```
<global>
    <template>
            <email>
                <design_email_header_custom_black translate="label" module="custom_module">
                    <label>Email - Header (CUSTOM BLACK)</label>
                    <file>html/header-custom-black.html</file>
                    <type>text</type>
                </design_email_header_custom_black>
                <design_email_header_custom_white translate="label" module="custom_module">
                    <label>Email - Header (CUSTOM WHITE)</label>
                    <file>html/header-custom-white.html</file>
                    <type>text</type>
                </design_email_header_custom_white>
                <design_email_footer_custom_black translate="label" module="custom_module">
                    <label>Email - Footer (CUSTOM BLACK)</label>
                    <file>html/footer-custom-black.html</file>
                    <type>text</type>
                </design_email_footer_custom_black>
                <design_email_footer_custom_white translate="label" module="custom_module">
                    <label>Email - Footer (CUSTOM WHITE)</label>
                    <file>html/footer-custom-white.html</file>
                    <type>text</type>
                </design_email_footer_custom_white>
            </email>
        </template>
</global>
```

So you have these options to select from:

> System > Configuration > Design > Transactional Email

Answer (score 1):

This may help explain it:
[Use multiple footers for email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54025/use-multiple-footers-for-email)
What they ask:

> Use multiple footers for email
>
> up vote 1 down vote favorite Is it possible to use multiple footers
>   for the Transactional Emails?
>
> So I want to use a specific footer for a new order email, and an other
>   footer for the shipment email.
>
> I currently load the footer with this line: {{template
>   config_path="design/email/footer"}}
>
> How can I load a specific template in the transactional email?

Answer (score 1):

**design/email/header** This refers to the configuration option *NOT* the template.

You could create a new module to add the option like so.

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <design>
            <groups>
                <email>
                    <fields>
                        <header2 translate="label">
                            <label>Email Header Template 2</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </header2>
```

Alternatively just create a new CMS static block and then insert it on top of your email content like so.

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="email-header-sales" }}
```

Replacing.

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
```

Comment: I needed to allow `cms/block` under System -> Permissions -> blocks

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to modify code in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml`

```
<global>
    <template>
            <email>
                <design_email_header translate="label" module="core">
                    <label>Email - Header</label>
                    <file>html/header2.html(your file name)</file>
                    <type>text</type>
                </design_email_header>
```

Instead of doing this in core file, try to do this in your custom module.