# How do I get current transactional email name?

Tags: transactional-mail

I want to display a custom text in the header.html template for different transactional email templates (order,account,password ....). My idea is to include a block:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='trans_emails/custom.phtml' type=$trans_template_name}}
```

Actually i don't know from where I should get the trans. email name. to pass it in the custom.phtml file. In that file I will put some conditions which  text will be displayed. My question is how do I get the current transactional email template name ?

thx

Comment: have you need store code like : en_US???

Comment: yes, is that should be a problem ? or ?

Answer (score 1):

See sales related template Here:

**System->Configuration->Sales Emails**

For customer related template see here:

**System->Configuration->Customer Configuration**

**About transactional emails:**

1. By default the templates are in `app/locale/en_US/template/email` where *en_US* is the locale code configured for the store.
2. They can be loaded into the database and edited using an editor within the browser. If an override is done that way, they are no longer loaded from the filesystem.

So first decide, if you want to keep them loading from the file system (and thus be able to version them) or from the database (so the merchant can easily edit the layout).

The footer and header are special:

The template is configured via the system configuration `System > Configuration > [General:Design] > Transactional Emails`. By default it's set to "Default from locale" which refers to the file `app/locale/en_US/template/email/html/header.html`.
[For more detail see here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54032/21339)

Comment: Yeah, but I have more then 10 t . emails template , with the same header.  For each t. emails I have a different header text. SO I included a block in header which calls a phtml file, where I want  to add that custom text for each template, but to do that I need to pass a variable to the block . My quess is to pass the t. email name (new order, new invoice etc) and in the phtml file I''ll do the following. IF ($x = "new order"){echo "t1"}elseif($x = "new invoice"){echo "t2"}elseif ...... did you got the idea ?

Comment: Please follow the linked answer it will help you